# 「暗から明へ」— how should this be read?

Tags: translation

[This article about a Japanese translation of Amanda Gorman's inauguration poem](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/byline/konosuyukiko/20210123-00218856/) is headlined as follows:

> 暗から明へーアマンダ・ゴーマン氏が米大統領就任式で朗読した詩の内容は？翻訳者の読み解き

Obviously the translation is:

> "From darkness to light" — what's in the poem that Amanda Gorman read out at Biden's inauguration? An analysis by the translator.

But how should 暗から明へ be read?

My best guess: 暗{やみ}から明{あかり}へ, but I'm not aware of やみ as a reading for 暗 (I am only aware of the reading くら in compounds, or otherwise 闇{やみ} if やみ is the intended reading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would read it as:

> [暗]{あん}から[明]{めい}へ

eg

[明]{めい}と[暗]{あん}
[正]{せい}と[負]{ふ}
[静]{せい}と[動]{どう}
[陰]{いん}と[陽]{よう}